# How do I list the bank's query on the same Memo line?

Tags: delphi

I have the following table:

```
tb_cars
------
BMW
VW
Chevrolet
```

The code I use is:

```
procedure Tfrm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer;
begin
for i := 0 to DBGridCars.SelectedRows.Count - 1 do
begin
  DM.tbCars.Bookmark := DBGridCars.SelectedRows.Items[i];
  memoTags.Lines.Add((DM.tbCars.FieldByName('car').AsString) + ',' );
      end;
end;
```

If I select 2 cars in the DBGrid

The same is displayed:

```
VM,
Chevrolet,
```

There is a possibility to display:

```
VM, Chevrolet
```

On the same line without the last character ","?

Comment: Declare a local string variable (say `s: string;`). In the `for` loop, instead of adding the strings from the field to the memo, concatenate them to the local string variable (`s := s + (DM.tbCars.FieldByName('car').AsString) + ',';`). After the `for` loop, remove the last comma and add the string variable to the memo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what Tom stated in the comments, but you can use your loop variable count to know whether or not this is your first selection (and you only need the car name) or if it is an additional selection (and you need the comma before the car name).

```
procedure Tfrm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer;
 s: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to DBGridCars.SelectedRows.Count - 1 do
  begin
    DM.tbCars.Bookmark := DBGridCars.SelectedRows.Items[i];

    if i = 0 then // first selection
      s := DM.tbCars.FieldByName('car').AsString
    else // additional selections
      s := s + ', ' + DM.tbCars.FieldByName('car').AsString;
  end;
    memoTags.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Comment: I prefer the pattern `if Length(Arr) > 0 then s := Arr[0]; for i := 1 to High(Arr) do s := s + ', ' + Arr[i]` because it is unnecessary to test if `i = 0` or not all `N` times. But in this context it doesn't matter of course.

Comment: It worked separately.

If I select 3 cars, 3 lines are displayed with one, two and three. The right thing would be to display only those selected in the DBGrid, which would be the last line.

VM
VM, Chevrolet
VM, Chevrolet, Fiat

Comment: @RalfK I was missing an end, which I fixed. You want make sure the line where it adds to the memo is outside of the `for` loop.